# Obtener el último ID de un registro de mi base de datos Sql y mostrarlo en un mensaje de un form en C#

Tags: c#, tsql

Mi duda es si es posible obtener el ID de mi último registro en la parte donde dice: MessageBox.Show($"La persona fue ingresada con el id..." Es una aplicación que solo utilizará la misma persona siempre. Se que ese dato lo puedo obtener con el @@indetity o scope, pero no tengo ni idea de como declararlo para obtener el dato.

Es mi primer pregunta, espero no molestar con ello.

```
private void Btn1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Mi cadena de conexion");
        conexion.Open();

        string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Tb1 (Nombre,Direccion,Telefono,Correo,Interes,Monto,Vence) VALUES (@Nombre,@Direccion,@Telefono,@Correo,@Interes,@Monto,@vence)";
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);


        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", Txtbox2.Text);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Direccion", Txtbox3.Text);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefono", Txtbox4.Text);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Correo", Txtbox5.Text);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Interes", Txtbox6.Text);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Monto", Txtbox7.Text);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vence", DateTimePicker1.Value);

        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conexion.Close();
        MessageBox.Show($"La persona fue ingresada, su id es ");
    }
```

---

Lo estoy intentando de este modo, añadi un Textbox y un boton, que segun yo una vez insertada la informacion al presionar el boton en el cual quiero que muestre el dato,deberia mostrar el ultimo ID insertado, pero simplemente no sucede nada, no marca error ni tampoco muestra el dato :( Asi tan cual como tengo en el codigo asi se llama mi tabla y tambien el nombre de la columna. Es un identity.

Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias de nuevo.

```
    private void Btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(Mi cadena de conexion);
        conexion.Open();

        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("Select * From Tb1 where IdPrestamo = @IdPrestamo",conexion);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdPrestamo", Txtbox8.Text);

        SqlDataReader registro = comando.ExecuteReader();


        if (registro.Read())
        {
            Txtbox8.Text = registro["IdPrestamo"].ToString();
        }

        conexion.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Creo que pensandolo bien desactivare esta funcion del auto-incrementable, ya que creo que me puede causar un conflicto al momento en que la persona vaya a eliminar a "x" cliente una vez realizado "x" pago, es decir; espacios vacios que ya no pueda recuperar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si alguien tiene el mismo problema que yo tenia,les comparto el codigo de la manera en como me funciono.Hice pruebas en la app y efectivamente ya me arroja el ultimo registro insertado en mi base de datos y me lo muestra en el mensaje que yo queria.

Gracias a todos y que pasen buena noche.

Este es el codigo:

private void Btn1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Cadena de conexion");
            conexion.Open();

```
        int idPrestamo = 0;

        string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Tb1 ( Nombre,Direccion,Telefono,Correo,Interes,Monto,Vence) VALUES (@Nombre,@Direccion,@Telefono,@Correo,@Interes,@Monto,@vence) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);

        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", Txtbox2.Text);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Direccion", Txtbox3.Text);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefono", Txtbox4.Text);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Correo", Txtbox5.Text);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Interes", Txtbox6.Text);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Monto", Txtbox7.Text);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vence", DateTimePicker1.Value);

        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdPrestamo", Txtbox1.Text);
        idPrestamo = Convert.ToInt32(comando.ExecuteScalar());



        conexion.Close();
        MessageBox.Show($"La persona fue ingresada, su id es " + Convert.ToString(idPrestamo));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Para esto puedes utilizar [OUTPUT CLAUSE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) si tienes tu columna ID como IDENTITY en conjunto de ExecuteScalar

Para el siguiente ejemplo tengo un projecto de consola que agrega una letra A una tabla con ID (Identity) y autonumerica, y otra columna de ejemplo en donde inserto la letra A.

En el INSERT va  `output INSERTED.ID` que es el valor del ID agregado a la tabla y que se obtiene al ejecutarse cmd.ExecuteScalar(), este valor lo asigno a la variable modified.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
                    con.Open();
                    var algo = "a";
                    int modified = 0;
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" INSERT INTO ejemplo ([texto]) output INSERTED.ID VALUES ( '" + algo + "') ", con))
                    {

                        modified = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    }

                    con.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("el IDingresado es " + modified);

}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Después que valides que el método ExecuteNonQuery afectó más de una fila, puedes mandar a llamar un procedimiento almacenado o un query teniendo ya la conexión abierta utilizando la función SCOPE_IDENTITY()

```
Select IdInserted = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

En un `DataReader` o llenando un `DataTable` podrás obtener ese registro

Espero te sirva